# Map object changing array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On an Angular application I have the following object with an array of requirements:

```
var source = {
  position: "xyz",
  requirements: [
    { a: { code: "a1", name: "a1" }, b: { code: "b1", name: "b1" } },
    { a: { code: "a2", name: "a2" }, b: { code: "b2", name: "b2" } }
  ]
};
```

I need to create a copy of this object as follows:

```
var target = {
  position: "xyz",
  requirements: [
    { acode: "a1", bcode: "b1" },
    { acode: "a2", bcode: "b2" }
  ]
};
```

So only the 'a' codes and 'b' codes are picked ...

What would be the best way to map such an object?

Comment: `.map(x => {acode: x.a.code, bcode: x.b.code})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to "copy" the object in this case. Then just map over the `requirements`.

```js
var source = {
  position: "xyz",
  requirements: [
    { a: { code: "a1", name: "a1" }, b: { code: "b1", name: "b1" } },
    { a: { code: "a2", name: "a2" }, b: { code: "b2", name: "b2" } }
  ]
};

var copy = Object.assign({}, source);
copy.requirements = copy.requirements.map(item => {
  return {acode: item.a.code, bcode: item.b.code}
});

console.log(source);
console.log(copy);
```

Comment: I need to create a copy of source, e.g., target with the new format. Not changing the source. This is I am sending target to an API in the required format but not wanting to change the format that the client is using.

Comment: @MiguelMoura, sorry I missed that case. I've updated the answer to "copy" the original object.

Comment: using simply "var copy = source" would not make the same as Object.create?

Comment: Nope, doing `var copy = source` will not work because `copy` would then point to the same piece of memory as `source`. Which means that any changes to `copy` would be reflected in `source.`

Comment: `Object.create()` doesn't make copies, you probably want `Object.assign({}, source)`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Although using assign only creates a "shallow copy" as well, I think it is the right option here.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop around and do this

```
var source = {
  position: "xyz",
  requirements: [
    { a: { code: "a1", name: "a1" }, b: { code: "b1", name: "b1" } },
    { a: { code: "a2", name: "a2" }, b: { code: "b2", name: "b2" } }
  ]
};

var target ={};
var innerArray = [];
for(var key in source) {
  if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if(typeof source[key] === 'string') {
       target[key] = source[key];   
    } else {
      for(var i = 0; i < source[key].length; i++) {
        var temp = {};
        temp.acode = source[key][i].a.code;
        temp.bcode = source[key][i].b.code;
        innerArray.push(temp);
      }
      target[key] = innerArray;    
    }
  }
}

console.log(target);
```

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Refatrafi/Lgryf2kv/12/